# Playing a sound in webforms without it being reset because of PostBack

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm an English teacher/starting programmer who's making a browser game for his class. I managed to set up a sound loop in HTML using code taken from another question and it works just fine, but I ran into a problem I haven't been able to solve. I'm using C# for the codebehind, and every time a button is pressed there's a Postback and the page is reloaded. My problem is that this resets the sound that started playing, which makes it impossible to play songs properly.

Here's the HTML code I'm using:

```
<NOEMBED><BGSOUND SRC="/sound/tutorial.wav" LOOP="2"></NOEMBED>
<EMBED SRC="/sound/tutorial.mp3" HEIGHT="0" WIDTH="0" AUTOSTART="TRUE">
</EMBED>
```

I hope this hasn't been answered yet, I checked and couldn't find anything. I'd appreciate a hand!

Comment: Sounds like you need to use AJAX

Comment: There are a couple ways you could address this.  You could create HTML frames where the post-back behavior is happening in one frame while the audio is playing in another.  Or you could remove the post-back behavior and use JavaScript/AJAX to make requests to the server without reloading the page.

Comment: Your only solution would be to prevent the postback (i.e. do an AJAX call instead of a postback). Unless you want to try to store the current position and then replay from there on load, but there will still be a brief silence in that case...

Comment: You should look into the aspnet 'UpdatePanel`. It does ajax posts instead of a full PostBack.